# Graph API: IDs of Microsoft Teams entities can be duplicate?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

In our code, we have this assumption that IDs of all Microsoft Teams entities (e.g. Team, Channel, Tab) in a Microsoft O365 tenant are unique. (These IDs are returned by the Graph API queries.)

Microsoft document is not very clear on this. I can see that most of the IDs are GUIDs so it looks like a safe assumption and I think can assume that these entities can not have duplicate ID in a tenant. Let me know if anyone has seen any different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

These are **G**uids, as you say, so they should be "globally" unique, aside from a specific tenant. Be aware though that the Id of the "General" channel in a team is actually the same Id as the team itself, so you might see some "duplication" from that perspective.

Comment: Thanks. Even in the case of the General channel, I can see ID as 19:hfOtOxUDd1Bqd5wQeYCaW75VMTlAqtCjxi07ui5NGJQ1@thread.tacv2 whereas the corresponding Team id is 03d2a172-87bd-43e4-9605-7d73eb20abc0. So it looks like there is no possibility of duplication here as well.

Comment: yes that will be unique. I think the IDs might match using the Graph API (Team Id and General Channel Id) - I can't recall exactly offhand